# Typing issue pass selector to dispatched action as parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to dispatch an action when as selector changes value. so I passe the selector with a subscription to avoid passing an observable

```
selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsByBranch));

this.store.dispatch(new GetDirectionsOnGraph(this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$.subscribe()))
```

I get this error

```
(property) BranchKpisComponent.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$: Observable<ISchedules>
Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISchedules'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'Subscription'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole code is not correct

this `this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$.subscribe()` will return a subscription, not the value

also each time you dispatch an action, you create a new subscription, which will result to unexpected behavior and memory leak

you can separately subscribe to this one time (in `ngOnInit` for example)

```
this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$
.subscribe(value => {
  this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopupValue = value;
})
```

then later

```
this.store.dispatch(new GetDirectionsOnGraph(this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopupValue))
```

Note: Don't forget to unsubscribe from `this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$` otherwise it will case memory leak

Comment: When should I unsubscribe ?

Comment: It depends, usually ngOnDestroy